# Passing different classnames to posts in PHP

Tags: php, css

I've got a blog system on my site. The text gets inserted into a database and then selected again. I have the option to post between two types of blog posts.
There are two submit buttons for each. They both execute the same code that inserts the text, because I want both blog posts to go to the same table.

```
 <?php
              include_once("config.php");
              $query = "SELECT * FROM pages";   
              $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);        

              if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
              {   
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
              {
              $pagetitle = $row['pagetitle'];
              $message = $row['message'];        

              echo 
                  '<article class="topcontent">                       
                     <div class="mct">
                          <h2>
                              '.$pagetitle .'</h2>
                     </div><br>
                     <p class="post-text"><br>    
                              '.$message.'</p>                          
                    </article>                                        
                  </form>
                  </div>   
                     ';}              

                 //IF ADMIN LOGGED IN, POST BLOGPOST WHEN BUTTON CLICKED
                  if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
                  {
                      echo '</nav>
                      <br><br>  <div class="blog">
                      <form id="sent" action="sent.php" method="post">Post new blog<br>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Title" method="POST" name="pagetitle" /><br><br>
                      <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea><br>
                      <input type="submit" name="postsent" value="Confirm" />
                      </form></div>'; 
                  }   

              //IF ADMIN LOGGED IN, POST COLLAGE WHEN BUTTON CLICKED
              if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
                  {
                      echo '</nav>
                      <br><br>  <div class="collage">
                      <form id="sent"  action="sent.php" method="post">Post new collage<br>
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Title" method="POST" name="pagetitle" /><br><br>
                      <textarea id="collage" name="message"></textarea><br>
                      <input type="submit" name="collagesent"  value="Confirm" />
                      </form></div>'; 
                  }   
      ?>
```

The issue is that I don't know how to pass an HTML id or class to the posts so that I can style them differently in CSS. I've tried to use a variable for the article class that is defined differently depending on which button is clicked, not as shown in the code above, it didn't work.

I simply want the class for the text that gets inserted into the database to be different. How do I do that?

EDIT:

The code that posts the data into the table.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (pagetitle, message) VALUES ('$_POST[pagetitle]','$_POST[message]')";
//the insertion into the table of the database 

if ($MySQLi_CON->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: ". $sql . "" . $MySQLi_CON->error;
}
```

Second edit:

```
echo '<article class="topcontent">
    <div class="mct">
    <h2> ' . $pagetitle .'</h2>
    </div><br>
    <p class="post-text"><br>'.$message.'</p>
    <div class=" . ($row[\'type\'] == 2 ? "topcontent" : "othertopcontent") . "> 
    </article>' ;
    //I want 'type 2' to be given a different article classname that's not 'topcontent'. Elsewise, it should always be posted in 'topcontent'.
```

Comment: You need an additional field in your table that keeps the class or some kind of type_id indicates the post type determined by the clicked submit button that you can get within POST in PHP so you can read it and change class accordingly when you display the text.

Comment: How would the code need to look for that?

Comment: how looks your current code processing posted html form?

Comment: I edited the question with that code.

Comment: first you need to check which submit button pressed -> if (isset($_POST['collagesent'])) { $type = 1;  } else if (isset($_POST['postsent'])) { $type = 2; } then use the $type as the new table field value. Then you need to retrieve type field value to decide which class to print in the view.

Comment: I got to the point where I pass the $type variable into a new table field value, like you recommended. I can now select which types of posts I want to see, or both based on the types. But I don't know what the logical code needs to be in order to change the class of the blogpost based on the type of the variable that goes into its query.

Comment: let's say your new field name is "type". so you get $row['type']. You use it in the echo with condition. Something like this <p class=" . ($row['type'] == 1 ? "post-text" : "special-text") . "> means you print the class name according to type value. So do you now have a type field in your database and populate accordingly? What is the field name?

Comment: I am using "type" as the field name. I updated the question with how I would use your line of code in your most recent comment, but still it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Please try the code I posted. debug for $row['type'] value to make sure you get what you need. Make sure topcontent and othertopcontent class names are valid for div and not overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to edit you made and assuming that you are fetching type field value from the database:

```
if ($row['type'] == 2) {
    $className = "topcontent";
} else {
    $className = "othertopcontent";
}

echo '<article class="topcontent">
    <div class="mct">
    <h2> ' . $pagetitle .'</h2>
    </div><br>
    <p class="post-text"><br>'.$message.'</p>
    <div class="' . $className . '"> 
    </article>' ;
```

Comment: That is the code I needed! Thanks very much for your help and effort. 

I had to tweak the code a bit to get the desired result, '<article class="'.$className.'">'.